# Getting Calling Object for Proxied Prototype Properties

Tags: javascript

I have a setup like this, where a prototype contains some data, and I can create instances from it:

```
const myPrototype = {
  someSimpleProp: 5,
  someComplexProp: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }
};

function createInstance() {
  return Object.create(myPrototype);
}
```

This works great for simple fields. At creation, all instances share the prototype data, and if I set the value of `someSimpleProp` on an instance, it shadows the prototype data instead of mutating it. This is particularly useful to me since it means I can serialize the instance and I'll only get the diff.

The problem I am running into is with complex fields like `someComplexProp`. If I set `someComplexProp.x`, it doesn't shadow the prototype - it just mutates it.

I've been trying to achieve something similar using proxies (in practice I'd have to recursively proxy, but I'm only doing it once here):

```
const myPrototype = {
  someSimpleProp: 5,
  someComplexProp: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }
};
myPrototype.someComplexProp = new Proxy(myPrototype.someComplexProp, {
  set(target, property, value, receiver) {
    // clone the prototype someComplexProp onto the instance, and then set the prop on that clone
    // But I can't figure out how to get a ref to the instance
  }
});

function createInstance() {
  return Object.create(myPrototype);
}
```

I've figured out how to solve all of the other problems, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a ref to the object where I actually did the assignment. `target` and `receiver` both point to the field on the prototype. What I need is to access the `this` context where I did the assignment.

My goal is to keep all of this prototyping out of sight of the other people writing in this system. Ideally, they should just be able to do normal assignment, and I use proxies to handle the details of the cloning under the hood. Am I out of luck? Do I need to give up on using normal assignment and just make my own `set` that users actually pass `this` into?

Comment: Proxies are best avoided unless there's no other option, they're weird, slow, and can be unintuitive. Best approach here would be to just change `createInstance` to return the whole (new) object.

Comment: That would not be the best approach for my needs. There is a reason I did it this way rather than using typical inheritance where data props are copied instead of handled via prototyping.

Comment: You mentioned that this allows you to serialize only the differences between a  particular object and the defaults in the prototype. Is that the only reason for doing this, or are there others?

Comment: There are others. And if there's no way to achieve this, I am comfortable writing alternatives. I just wanted to know if there's some way to achieve this particular thing that I'm missing, in the hope that I could engineer this to allow for normal assignment with `=` in other scripts and handle the details under the hood like this.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't someComplexProp also be an object with defaults set via a prototype?

Comment: Also, given the warnings here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf is there any reason you are not using Object.create()?

Comment: Imagine that `someComplexProp` is even more complex - maybe a few nested levels deep. I'd have to recursively build out a shell of empty objects to prototype each sub-object to. For several reasons, I'd like to avoid that. Also, in the actual code, I did use `Object.create` - just wrote this up quickly without thinking too deeply since that part is largely irrelevant to the question here. I've edited it.

Comment: @samueldcorbin What's the typical access pattern on these deeply nested complex objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at responses and thinking on this more, it looks like the answer is no - this is not possible.

You would need a way to pass the `this` where the assignment was done to the `set` on the proxy, and the built-in proxying doesn't pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to proxy the top-level `myPrototype` object itself, not the one stored in `someComplexProp`. In that case, the `receiver` will indeed be the instance inheriting from the prototype.

```
const myPrototype = new Proxy({
  someSimpleProp: 5,
  someComplexProp: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
  }
}, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    const value = target[property];
    if (Object(value) !== value) return value;
    return receiver[property] = Object.create(value);
  }
});

function createInstance() {
  return Object.create(myPrototype);
}

const a = createInstance();
console.log(a.someSimpleProp); // 5
const b = createInstance();
a.someSimpleProp = 10;
console.log(b.someSimpleProp); // still 5

console.log(a.someComplexProp.x); // 1
console.log(a.someComplexProp == b.someComplexProp); // false (sic!)
a.someComplexProp.x = 7;
console.log(b.someComplexProp.x); // still 1
```

My simple implementation above does not handle further nesting, and it does copy-on-read instead of copy-on-write, but you can extend that if you want. Creating the object on read should not be costly though, you will always have to create *some* object to store which ancestor you accessed, and also you'll want to guarantee `a.someComplexProp == a.someComplexProp`.

Comment: Creating an object on read doesn't work for me here, unfortunately. The whole goal is to avoid creating the instance properties unless there's a write. The more I think about this, the more I think what I wanted is just not doable with proxies - I think it'll have to be done with a call that can actually capture the `this` at assignment. Not quite as clean for users of this system, but probably as clean as I can make it.

Comment: @samueldcorbin Not sure why you are trying to avoid creating the properties. Are you trying to (prematurely?) optimise something? Notice that if these objects are meant to be mutable (writable), you must ensure that `a.someComplexProp !== b.someComplexProp` or you'd get really weird effects (and unhappy users). And you need to ensure this when `.someComplexProp` is accessed already, that's just the order of operations and you cannot predict the future.

Comment: The prototypes in this case are never mutated, and the instances never share refs except via the prototype. This is a toy example illustrating a problem I was having, but I'm working with a large, existing system - none of this is premature, and it isn't just an attempt at optimization. I asked the question because it was the question I wanted an answer to - if this was possible and I was overlooking something. It looks like the answer is "no". That's fine.

Comment: So what's the actual problem you are having? And what are you trying to optimise - performance, memory usage, something else? Instead of writing to `receiver[property]` immediately you could try using a `WeakRef`, but I doubt that's actually any lighter-weight.